# Parent state undefined in componentDidMount event of the child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm setting the state of my parent component in `componentDidMount` and passing its value to a child component via `props`, but even though the input is filled, when I run `console.log(this.props.value)` in the `componentDidMount` event of the child component, it is `undefined`. I need this value updated in this event.

How to get the correct `prop` value in this scenario?

Example code:

```js
class Text extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount(){
    console.log(this.props.value);
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
    <div>
     <input type="text" value={this.props.value} />
     </div>
    );
  }
}

class Form extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: {}
    };
  }
  
  componentDidMount(){
    let data = {
      RequestId: "0000-000"
      }
      
      this.setState({ data });
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <Text value={this.state.data["RequestId"]} />
    );
  }
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Form />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.5.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.5.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happen in your case is the child component mount before the logic change from the parent. Here a way to make it work. Also what you can do it's use the componentDidUpdate lifecycle method to trigger the change.

**Remember componentDidMount get call only ONE time. So at the moment the parent get it the child is already mount. But as you can see the value of the input is filled that's because react component rerender on props change. BUT not REMOUNT.**

With the if part here, the component render only when data RequestId is filled, so we can then trigger the componentDidMount with the value you want.

```js
class Text extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount(){
    console.log(this.props.value);
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
    <div>
     <input type="text" value={this.props.value} />
     </div>
    );
  }
}

class Form extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: {}
    };
  }
  
  componentDidMount(){
    let data = {
      RequestId: "0000-000"
      }
      
      this.setState({ data });
  }
  
  render() {
    if (!this.state.data["RequestId"]) { return null }
    return (
      <Text value={this.state.data["RequestId"]} />
    );
  }
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Form />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.5.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.5.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I have tested using componentDidUpdate instead of componentDidMount in the child component and it worked as well. What would be the best way to solve this?

Comment: @MarcellAlves depend of what you trying to do, in your case what you try to achieve ? From what I see the input have already the value.

Comment: I need to update the parent's error state (I've removed this logic for concision), since it's a form. I think the componentDidUpdate way will be the best fit for me. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, but I have a doubt: the child's onChange event will get fired at the first render?

Comment: no the onChange get call when you type in the input. You can maybe create a method if you want to make sure to not use memory on every render. But here it's just for showing you can use a callback method for updating the parent.